# Shrink database after removing extra data

Tags: sql-server, shrink

We have a need to fit a database in 4GB in order to use SQL Server Express Edition. I started from a 7GB database, and found a lot of unneeded records, and deleted them. After shrinking, the database size is 4.6GB, and 748 MB is free *(according to database properties)*.

However, when I execute `exec sp_spaceused`, I have interesting results:

```
DatabaseName    Database_size   unallocation space
xxxxxx          4726.50 MB      765.42 MB
```

```
Reserved        Data          index_size      unused
3899472 KB      1608776 KB    1448400 KB      842296 KB
```

Any ideas, how can I release at least some of this unused space?
Also I know table, which occupied it.

**Update:** is it worth to trying to rebuild table indexes?

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Production.Product REBUILD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After index recreation, using this command:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Production.Product REBUILD
```

and than I run SHRINK command again - end up with 2.5G database.

Comment: Using this command for every table, I finally get 1.4G database, which is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

First set recovery mode to simple, make backup and shrink all files (data and logs) seprately; use 'move pages to start of database' (or how exactly that is named) option for shrinking.

Then you may consider index defragmenting, helped us in similar circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already shrunk your database, then give `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE TRUNCATEONLY` a try.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa258287).